# How to install ffmpeg 6 in a dockerized Debian 11?

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, docker

I have a Debian docker image that is running my web app, this is the head of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.2

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

# Install ffmpeg for video processing
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

The Debian that is installed is version 11.1:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
11.1
```

The ffmpeg that is installed is 4.3.5:

```
ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.3.5-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
```

I make intensive use of ffmpeg on this docker image, and I would like to have the last version that [right now it is 6.1.1](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#releases).

How can I configure my Dockerfile so that the last version of ffmpeg is installed when the image is built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it can be seen [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Downstreams), on Debian ffmpeg 6.1 is only available as Sid (unstable) package. There's no bullseye (11) [backport](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ffmpeg&searchon=names&section=all&suite=bullseye-backports) either. There are multiple ways to go about it:

- use [Alpine Ruby](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) base instead, e.g. `3.0.2-alpine` if you for some reason need that version. Alpine has latest [6.1.1 builds](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=ffmpeg&branch=edge&repo=&arch=&maintainer=). This is the easiest and most recommended way to proceed I'd say, unless you require Debian for a specific reason.
- build your own Ruby container based on distro that has access to latest ffmpeg and the Ruby version you need
- build ffmpeg from source, e.g. [instructions here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). Not really recommended in Dockerfile and you need to know what you're doing, plus dependencies might be missing or unstable also.